# Is Bitcoin a stack of cards which will collapse?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Is it possible, that once all the bicoins are minted, the code is designed in such a way, that the entire ledger or stack of cards, comes tubling down and all cryptos are deleted?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. The people behind the code are invested in the success of bitcoin.

If they designed it to crash to nothing, even way off in the future (around 2140), their motives would be pulled in to question and deflate confidence in bitcoin today.

Also, remember the code is public and someone would have spotted such a deliberate undermining of the coin.